# Root exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize Class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss-eap-7

Trying to deploy jboss eap 7 server in linux environment which got deployed in windows (same server configuration is working fine in windows) giving this issue

```
RROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) Context initialization failed: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportBeanService': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: 
Failed to lookup EAR_Name/Module/Bean!com.src.ejb.BeanRemote [Root exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize Class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73]
```

Any idea what can be the issue here or if you guys have faced the same issue please respond

this is my standalone.sh (this is the only file which is different from my windows version)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Use --debug to activate debug mode with an optional argument to specify the port.
# Usage : standalone.sh --debug
#         standalone.sh --debug 9797

# By default debug mode is disable.
DEBUG_MODE="${DEBUG:-false}"
DEBUG_PORT="${DEBUG_PORT:-8787}"
SERVER_OPTS=""
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
      --debug)
          DEBUG_MODE=true
          if [ -n "$2" ] && [ "$2" = `echo "$2" | sed 's/-//'` ]; then
              DEBUG_PORT=$2
              shift
          fi
          ;;
      -Djava.security.manager*)
          echo "ERROR: The use of -Djava.security.manager has been removed. Please use the -secmgr command line argument or SECMGR=true environment variable."
          exit 1
          ;;
      -secmgr)
          SECMGR="true"
          ;;
      --)
          shift
          break;;
      *)
          SERVER_OPTS="$SERVER_OPTS '$1'"
          ;;
    esac
    shift
done

DIRNAME=`dirname "$0"`
PROGNAME=`basename "$0"`
GREP="grep"

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that
MAX_FD="maximum"

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false;
darwin=false;
linux=false;
solaris=false;
freebsd=false;
other=false
case "`uname`" in
    CYGWIN*)
        cygwin=true
        ;;

    Darwin*)
        darwin=true
        ;;
    FreeBSD)
        freebsd=true
        ;;
    Linux)
        linux=true
        ;;
    SunOS*)
        solaris=true
        ;;
    *)
        other=true
        ;;
esac

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin ; then
    [ -n "$JBOSS_HOME" ] &&
        JBOSS_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JBOSS_HOME"`
    [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] &&
        JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
    [ -n "$JAVAC_JAR" ] &&
        JAVAC_JAR=`cygpath --unix "$JAVAC_JAR"`
fi

# Setup JBOSS_HOME
RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME=`cd "$DIRNAME/.." >/dev/null; pwd`
if [ "x$JBOSS_HOME" = "x" ]; then
    # get the full path (without any relative bits)
    JBOSS_HOME=$RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME
else
 SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME"; pwd`
 if [ "$RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME" != "$SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
   echo ""
   echo "   WARNING:  JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur."
   echo ""
   echo "             JBOSS_HOME: $JBOSS_HOME"
   echo ""
   sleep 2s
 fi
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

# Read an optional running configuration file
if [ "x$RUN_CONF" = "x" ]; then
    RUN_CONF="$DIRNAME/standalone.conf"
fi
if [ -r "$RUN_CONF" ]; then
    . "$RUN_CONF"
fi

JAVA_OPTS="-Denvprop.loc="/home/user1/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/environment.properties" -Djboss.ejb.client.properties.file.path="/home/user1/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/jboss-ejb-client.properties" -Dfa.dfprimary=DFSERVER1 -Dfa.dfsecondary=DFSERVER1 -Dfa.servername=DFSERVER1 -Dfa.init.log4j=true -Dfa.log.config.location="/home/scm/FirstGen_JBOSS7/config/log4j.xml" -DLog2DB=true -server -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n"

# Set debug settings if not already set
if [ "$DEBUG_MODE" = "true" ]; then
    DEBUG_OPT=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-agentlib:jdwp"`
    if [ "x$DEBUG_OPT" = "x" ]; then
        JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=n"
    else
        echo "Debug already enabled in JAVA_OPTS, ignoring --debug argument"
    fi
fi

# Setup the JVM
if [ "x$JAVA" = "x" ]; then
    if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" != "x" ]; then
        JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    else
        JAVA="java"
    fi
fi

if [ "$PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS" != "true" ]; then
    # Check for -d32/-d64 in JAVA_OPTS
    JVM_D64_OPTION=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-d64"`
    JVM_D32_OPTION=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-d32"`

    # Check If server or client is specified
    SERVER_SET=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-server"`
    CLIENT_SET=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-client"`

    if [ "x$JVM_D32_OPTION" != "x" ]; then
        JVM_OPTVERSION="-d32"
    elif [ "x$JVM_D64_OPTION" != "x" ]; then
        JVM_OPTVERSION="-d64"
    elif $darwin && [ "x$SERVER_SET" = "x" ]; then
        # Use 32-bit on Mac, unless server has been specified or the user opts are incompatible
        "$JAVA" -d32 $JAVA_OPTS -version > /dev/null 2>&1 && PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="-d32" && JVM_OPTVERSION="-d32"
    fi

    if [ "x$CLIENT_SET" = "x" -a "x$SERVER_SET" = "x" ]; then
        # neither -client nor -server is specified
        if $darwin && [ "$JVM_OPTVERSION" = "-d32" ]; then
            # Prefer client for Macs, since they are primarily used for development
            PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -client"
        else
            PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -server"
        fi
    fi

    # EAP6-121 feature disabled
    # Enable rotating GC logs if the JVM supports it and GC logs are not already enabled
    #NO_GC_LOG_ROTATE=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-verbose:gc"`
    #if [ "x$NO_GC_LOG_ROTATE" = "x" ]; then
        # backup prior gc logs
        #mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.0" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.0" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.1" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.1" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.2" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.2" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.3" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.3" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.4" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.4" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.*.current" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.current" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #"$JAVA" $JVM_OPTVERSION -verbose:gc -Xloggc:"$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -version >/dev/null 2>&1 && mkdir -p $JBOSS_LOG_DIR && PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -verbose:gc -Xloggc:\"$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log\" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading"
    #fi

    JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS"
fi

if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULEPATH" = "x" ]; then
    JBOSS_MODULEPATH="$JBOSS_HOME/modules"
fi

if $linux; then
    # consolidate the server and command line opts
    CONSOLIDATED_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $SERVER_OPTS"
    # process the standalone options
    for var in $CONSOLIDATED_OPTS
    do
       # Remove quotes
       p=`echo $var | tr -d "'"`
       case $p in
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=*)
              JBOSS_BASE_DIR=`readlink -m ${p#*=}`
              ;;
         -Djboss.server.log.dir=*)
              JBOSS_LOG_DIR=`readlink -m ${p#*=}`
              ;;
         -Djboss.server.config.dir=*)
              JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR=`readlink -m ${p#*=}`
              ;;
       esac
    done
fi

if $solaris; then
    # consolidate the server and command line opts
    CONSOLIDATED_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $SERVER_OPTS"
    # process the standalone options
    for var in $CONSOLIDATED_OPTS
    do
       # Remove quotes
       p=`echo $var | tr -d "'"`
      case $p in
        -Djboss.server.base.dir=*)
             JBOSS_BASE_DIR=`echo $p | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
             ;;
        -Djboss.server.log.dir=*)
             JBOSS_LOG_DIR=`echo $p | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
             ;;
        -Djboss.server.config.dir=*)
             JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR=`echo $p | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
             ;;
      esac
    done
fi

# No readlink -m on BSD
if $darwin || $freebsd || $other ; then
    # consolidate the server and command line opts
    CONSOLIDATED_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $SERVER_OPTS"
    # process the standalone options
    for var in $CONSOLIDATED_OPTS
    do
       # Remove quotes
       p=`echo $var | tr -d "'"`
       case $p in
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=*)
              JBOSS_BASE_DIR=`cd ${p#*=} ; pwd -P`
              ;;
         -Djboss.server.log.dir=*)
              if [ -d "${p#*=}" ]; then
                JBOSS_LOG_DIR=`cd ${p#*=} ; pwd -P`
             else
                #since the specified directory doesn't exist we don't validate it
                JBOSS_LOG_DIR=${p#*=}
             fi
             ;;
         -Djboss.server.config.dir=*)
              JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR=`cd ${p#*=} ; pwd -P`
              ;;
       esac
    done
fi

# determine the default base dir, if not set
if [ "x$JBOSS_BASE_DIR" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_BASE_DIR="$JBOSS_HOME/standalone"
fi
# determine the default log dir, if not set
if [ "x$JBOSS_LOG_DIR" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_LOG_DIR="$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/log"
fi
# determine the default configuration dir, if not set
if [ "x$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR="$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/configuration"
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
    JBOSS_HOME=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_HOME"`
    JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
    JBOSS_MODULEPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_MODULEPATH"`
    JBOSS_BASE_DIR=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"`
    JBOSS_LOG_DIR=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"`
    JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"`
fi

if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULEPATH" = "x" ]; then
    JBOSS_MODULEPATH="$JBOSS_HOME/modules"
fi

# Process the JAVA_OPTS and fail the script of a java.security.manager was found
SECURITY_MANAGER_SET=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "java\.security\.manager"`
if [ "x$SECURITY_MANAGER_SET" != "x" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: The use of -Djava.security.manager has been removed. Please use the -secmgr command line argument or SECMGR=true environment variable."
    exit 1
fi

# Set up the module arguments
MODULE_OPTS=""
if [ "$SECMGR" = "true" ]; then
    MODULE_OPTS="$MODULE_OPTS -secmgr";
fi

# Display our environment
echo "========================================================================="
echo ""
echo "  JBoss Bootstrap Environment"
echo ""
echo "  JBOSS_HOME: $JBOSS_HOME"
echo ""
echo "  JAVA: $JAVA"
echo ""
echo "  JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"
echo ""
echo "========================================================================="
echo ""

while true; do
   if [ "x$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" = "x" ]; then
      # Execute the JVM in the foreground
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Standalone]\" $JAVA_OPTS \
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/server.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:"$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"/logging.properties\" \
         -jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         $MODULE_OPTS \
         -mp \""${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}"\" \
         org.jboss.as.standalone \
         -Djboss.home.dir=\""$JBOSS_HOME"\" \
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=\""$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"\" \
         "$SERVER_OPTS"
      JBOSS_STATUS=$?
   else
      # Execute the JVM in the background
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Standalone]\" $JAVA_OPTS \
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/server.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:"$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"/logging.properties\" \
         -jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         $MODULE_OPTS \
         -mp \""${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}"\" \
         org.jboss.as.standalone \
         -Djboss.home.dir=\""$JBOSS_HOME"\" \
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=\""$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"\" \
         "$SERVER_OPTS" "&"
      JBOSS_PID=$!
      # Trap common signals and relay them to the jboss process
      trap "kill -HUP  $JBOSS_PID" HUP
      trap "kill -TERM $JBOSS_PID" INT
      trap "kill -QUIT $JBOSS_PID" QUIT
      trap "kill -PIPE $JBOSS_PID" PIPE
      trap "kill -TERM $JBOSS_PID" TERM
      if [ "x$JBOSS_PIDFILE" != "x" ]; then
        echo $JBOSS_PID > $JBOSS_PIDFILE
      fi
      # Wait until the background process exits
      WAIT_STATUS=128
      while [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -ge 128 ]; do
         wait $JBOSS_PID 2>/dev/null
         WAIT_STATUS=$?
         if [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -gt 128 ]; then
            SIGNAL=`expr $WAIT_STATUS - 128`
            SIGNAL_NAME=`kill -l $SIGNAL`
            echo "*** JBossAS process ($JBOSS_PID) received $SIGNAL_NAME signal ***" >&2
         fi
      done
      if [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -lt 127 ]; then
         JBOSS_STATUS=$WAIT_STATUS
      else
         JBOSS_STATUS=0
      fi
      if [ "$JBOSS_STATUS" -ne 10 ]; then
            # Wait for a complete shudown
            wait $JBOSS_PID 2>/dev/null
      fi
      if [ "x$JBOSS_PIDFILE" != "x" ]; then
            grep "$JBOSS_PID" $JBOSS_PIDFILE && rm $JBOSS_PIDFILE
      fi
   fi
   if [ "$JBOSS_STATUS" -eq 10 ]; then
      echo "Restarting application server..."
   else
      exit $JBOSS_STATUS
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting snippet:
Failed to lookup FG_PMD_N6.2.2.4_20170828/ficclaim/ClaimsWebServiceBean!com.firstapex.fic.claims.ejb.ClaimsWebServiceBeanRemote

So it looks like a problem with a user application.

Maybe start with a 'clean' jboss application server (no user apps), then deploy them one by one.  You might get some clues as the troubled application deploys.